# Is there any simple way to check all possibilities of yes/no option in Bash?

Tags: bash, awk, aix

I am trying to implement a check for different possibilities of Yes/No. Below code is working fine but is there any simple way for doing this.

Note: I am using bash version 2.02.0.

```
read -p "Using dest path :${DESTPATH}" flag;
OPT=$(echo $flag|awk '{print tolower($0)}')
if [[ ${OPT:0:1} != 'y' ]]; then
     echo "Exiting..."; return
fi
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to call `awk` at all. You can take advantage of globbing:

```
read -p "Using dest path :${DESTPATH}" flag

if [[ $flag != [yY]* ]]; then
     echo "Exiting...";
     exit 1
fi
```

`[yY]*` will match any string starting with either `y` or `Y`

Comment: thanks for reply. But I was trying more combinations with regex, to make it more reliable.
But something is going wrong.

if [[ $flag != [yY][(eE|)][(sS|)] ]]; then

Answer (score 3):

```
case $flag in [Yy]* | sure | absolumatively)
    ;;
  *)
    echo Exiting
    exit 1;; 
esac
```

This is portable to traditional and POSIX `sh`. If you are on Bash version 4, you could examine `${flag,,}` to have the value normalized to lowercase.

Answer (score 2):

`typeset -l flag` before reading it:
You only need to check lowercase.

@anubhava answer is correct, using typeset and changing is optional.

```
typeset -l flag
read -p "Using dest path :${DESTPATH}" flag
if [[ $flag != y* ]]; then
     echo "Exiting...";
     exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Note that the `-l` flag to `typeset` was introduced in `bash` 4.

Comment: `-l` is handy; `-u` is the upper-case equivalent (but, as noted, requires Bash 4+). Also note that Bash prefers `declare` to `typeset` - the latter is considered obsolete. (`ksh`, by contrast, _only_ recognizes `typeset`).